# Getting Response message Review CeilingAmount while doing test payment by payflowpro API

Tags: asp.net, paypal, payflowpro

I have setup first time test application with payflowpro API. I am getting **PREFPSMSG=Review CeilingAmount** response . After lot of R&D did not find anything. Any help would be really appreciable.

TIA.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is a general response message that your Transaction Settings may be blocking this payment in your gateway account.

1. Login to the Payflow Gateway - https://manager.paypal.com/
2. Account Administration Under Manage Security Click "Transaction Settings"
3. Update “Maximum Amount per Transactions” to higher amount
4. Click "Confirm"

It may take up to an hour for the settings to be saved. After this time has elapsed, the payment should be able to post in your test account.